# What does Router module do in Express?

Tags: express, module, router

Sorry if is it a simple question, but I search and read documents but yet don't understand what exactly `Route` module do and is it for what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

When you go to "www.user.com", you expect to be given the homepage right? When you're writing your Express app, you probably have that location sitting in one JS file

Well, when you go to "www.user.com/me", you should expect to be served a different page right?

Now, you can write all of that logic in the same file for your app, but it would perhaps get super long if you wanted to serve more than just a couple pages on your application.

The Router module allows you to compartmentalize your different website paths into different JS files. Pretend like we moved our '/me' path into a me.js file.

Even though the paths, like "www.user.com/me", is in a different file, you can tell your main Express file where to find and use it. By doing so, you can still mount that Router module or "route handler" to your application even though it lives somewhere else.

The great thing about the router module is that each file isn't as long, you have a separation of concerns, and the files are more readable for you and your fellow collaborators.

Search for "express.Router" for more details here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Module definition: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3843/module